# Select Parent Node on the basis of same name child node at same level

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to select "Parent" node only if none of the child tag has value "fail". There can be multiple Child element its very dynamic.

**Sample Input:**

```
<Parent>
<Parent-bro> bro1</Parent-bro>
....
<Father>
<Father-bro>...</Father-bro>
<Child>pass</Child>
<Child>testing</Child>
<Child>fail</Child>

</Parent>
```

**Sample output**
Blank no node should get selected as one of the child element has value fail.

Incase of single child I was able to select using "Parent[//Father/Child/text()!='fail']".

But now since there can be one child element or 100 child element and i need search if any one of them has value "Fail". Select only if none of the tag contains value "Fail".
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select "Parent" node only if none of the child tag has value
>   "fail". There can be multiple Child element its very dynamic.

Not sure what you mean by "very dynamic". In your example the `Father` element is missing a closing tag - so it's not clear if `Child` is a child of `Father` or of  `Parent`.

This should work either way:

```
Parent[not(.//Child='fail')]
```

but an explicit path such as:

```
Parent[not(Father/Child='fail')]
```

or:

```
 Parent[not(Child='fail')]
```

is preferable.